# Why can't Mathematica draw a consistent mesh on a torus?

Tags: graphics3d

[image: Three attempts at drawing a torus]

All 3 images are produced using ParametricPlot3D  The left example is produced with no extra options.  Note that the black lines, which is all I really want to see, cut in and out and are not connected.  In the right example, the colors are gone, but the mesh lines are still broken up and the picture looks terrible.  In the middle frame, I've tried changing the PlotStyle so the faces are only 0.8 opaque.  This helps, but I don't want the surface to be transparent.  How can I draw a simple black and white mesh picture of a torus?

Code for middle picture:

```
SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D,
    Axes->False,
    Boxed->False,
    Mesh->20,
    Lighting -> {White},
    PlotStyle->FaceForm[{White,Opacity[0.8]}]
    ]
 ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]), Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]),Sin[t]
    },
    {u,0,2Pi},{t,0,2Pi}]
```

Comment: adding the options `PlotStyle->None`, `Mesh -> {20, 20}` and `BoundaryStyle -> Black`  seems to work in v9 (windows 10) and v11.3 (wolfram cloud).

Comment: @kgir Those options yield a transparent torus (for me), not an opaque one (my goal).  Can you post your image?

Comment: edgeloss, sorry i missed your requirement. Do the options  `PlotStyle -> White`, and `Lighting -> "Neutral"` help?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: What version of Mathematica and what hardware are you using under what operating system?

Comment: Followup:  I am still seeing the following strange behavior (which of course one can workaround):   The code  SetOptions[ParametricPlot3D,
        Axes->False,
        Boxed->False,
        Mesh->20,
        PlotStyle->Glow[White],
        MeshStyle->Thick
        ]


    g1 =    ParametricPlot3D[
        {Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]), Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]),Sin[t]
        }, {u,0,2Pi},{t,0,2Pi}]

g2 =    ParametricPlot3D[
        {Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]), Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2]+Cos[t]),Sin[t]
        }, {u,0,2Pi},{t,0,2Pi},
        MeshStyle->Thick
        ]

Answer (score 22):

I think you can do this:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2] + Cos[t]), 
  Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2] + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi + Pi/10}, {t, 0, 
  2 Pi + Pi/10}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> 20, 
  PlotStyle -> Glow[White], MeshStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: torus]

The main point is is to use `Glow` in the `PlotStyle` option to make the white surface independent of the lighting.

I also added a fix for another annoying shortcoming: the `Mesh` lines are drawn at subdivisions of the periodicity interval that leave a gap, unless you extend the parameter ranges by one interval size ($2\pi/n$ where $n$ is the number specified in the `Mesh` option).

Finally, I increased `PlotPoints` to make the lines smoother.

Instead of extending the parameter intervals, you can also fix the gaps in the mesh lines by adding `BoundaryStyle`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2] + Cos[t]), 
  Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2] + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Glow[White], 
 MeshStyle -> Thick, PlotPoints -> 100, BoundaryStyle -> Thick]
```

The ends of the torus surface in the given parametrization are considered a boundary curve and therefore don't get a mesh line. The `BoundaryStyle -> Thick` option adds lines where the mesh is missing.

Comment: `g= ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u]*(Sqrt[2] + Cos[t]), Sin[u]*(Sqrt[2] + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi + Pi/10}, {t, 0, 2 Pi + Pi/10}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Glow[White], MeshStyle -> Thick, PlotPoints -> 100]` Works well, except when I try `Export["pic.pdf",g]` the image is as attached. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsd14.png

Comment: @edgeloss. If I export to `pdf`, MMA `11.3` give me a nice torus.On Windows 8.1 64 bit.`Jens` code works perfect.